# iOS JSON Parsing, Format Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

So I was working on a project that required me to work with some JSON, I was running into a few issues regarding the best way of representing things. First of, this is how the JSON looks:

```
"phoneList": [
  {
    "phoneReason": "End of Contract",
    "phoneType": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "phoneType": "Android Smartphone"
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
```

I want to know the most appropriate way of representing this.

For example, I do know that that my phoneReason will just be a simple NSString while my phoneType is actually a NSArray. However,I wasn't sure how to represent a)the id, I know this is an integer, but should this be an NSInteger or an NSNumber and b)could someone point me in the direction of some sample code where I can understand how to model a dictionary object containing an integer and a string and also where I can understand how to model an array of dictionaries.

My other question is also similar in that say I'm actually posting something, how do I model this, specifically say for like dictionary type (JSON Curly Brace)objects that contain a number/integer and a string.

For example, this is the JSON I'm trying to model and then do something like this:

```
"phoneReason": "Upgrade",
"phoneInfo": {
  "id": "2"
},
```

//And then I want to pass ID

```
-(void) createOurRequest:(NSNumber *)id {

NSDictionary *myDictionary = @{
        @"phoneReason" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",   s  elf.dat.reason],
      //How do I then represent the phoneInfo element exactly?
};
```

Sorry, for the clumsy question, would really appreciate any guidance on modeling JSON in iOS or just generally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're asking questions a) and b), and also how to model a JSON.

a) The unfortunate thing with Obj-C is that **all collection elements have to be objects**. Integers are value types, so they will need to be converted to `NSNumber`s to work. However, if you're parsing a JSON string, the builtin JSON parser does it for you. I'll describe it below.

b) The model is based on the JSON. **You describe the object collection and the parser will determine the model for you**. In your example, you would have a `NSDictionary<NSString *: NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *: id>*>*>`. The innermost element has value of `id` because you can either have an `NSString` (`"End of Contract"`) or an `NSArray` (`"phoneType": [ { "id": 5, "phoneType": "Android Smartphone" } ]`)

Of course, the model is defined by your JSON, so if you run it through a parser, you get a structured object. You can access each element based on your model (`object[@"phoneList"][@"phoneReason"]`).

The class method to use is:

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data
                 options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt
                   error:(NSError **)error
```

Where you pass it a `NSData` representation of your string, options (or `0`), and a NSError pointer (`error*`). You get back a parsed JSON with the proper structure you defined.

```
NSDictionary *parsedJSONObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:NULL
```

I have no options to use and I know there will be no error, so I pass nothing for those parameters. The resulting object will be in whatever structure your JSON is.

Answer (score 0):

Using the objects and the json layout you provided in your first example, this is how I would go about creating the dictionaries and arrays to get the json in the format you specified. Hopefully this helps make it a little clearer for you.

```
// example constructor method
-(void) jsonStringWithPhoneReason:(NSString*)reason phoneId:(NSInteger)phoneId phoneType:(NSString*)phoneType
{
    // create device detail dictionary
    NSDictionary *deviceOneDetail = @{
                                      @"id" : @(phoneId),       // <- set phone id as NSNumber
                                      @"phoneType" : phoneType  // <- set your string phone type
                                      };

    // create device dictionary
    NSDictionary *deviceOne       = @{
                                      @"phoneReason" : reason,          // <- set your phone reason string
                                      @"phoneType" : @[deviceOneDetail] // <- set your phone type dictionary within an array
                                      };

    // create phone list dictionary with any device dictionaries you want to add
    NSDictionary *phoneListDict   = @{
                                      @"phoneList" : @[
                                                        deviceOne,      // <- add your device to the phone list array of dictionaries
                                                        // deviceTwo...
                                                        ]
                                      };

    NSString *jsonString = [self convertToJsonString:phoneListDict];    // <- convert the dictionary into a json string and use however you wish

    // your json string should now look like this assuming you pass 'End of Contract', 5 & 'Android Smartphone' as arguments to this method
    // {"phoneList":[{"phoneReason":"End of Contract","phoneType":[{"id":5,"phoneType":"Android Smartphone"}]}]}
}



-(NSString*) convertToJsonString:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
    NSError *error;

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                                                       options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                         error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSString *errorDesc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error creating json data from dictionary: %@", error.localizedDescription];
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", errorDesc);
        jsonData = nil;
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *returnString = nil;

    if(jsonData != nil)
    {
        returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    return returnString;

}
```